# Use Armadillo in Qt crashed

Tags: c++, qt, armadillo

I should do some work with Armadillo for some reason. But When I debug my code with Qt Creator, the code was crashed. I find where the question is but I did not understand why the crashed was happened. Some code can use but some not. Here is my code.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = paintertest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
test1.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    test1.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += D:/program/engineering/armadillo-8.200.2/include




win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -
llibblas
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -
L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -llibblas
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -llibblas

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -
lliblapack
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -
L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lliblapack
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lliblapack

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -
lliblapacke
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -
L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lliblapacke
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32/ -lliblapacke

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libBLAS_LAPACKwin32
```

mainwindow.h:

```
 #include <armadillo>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace arma;
    using namespace std;
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
 cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;

 mat A(2,3);  // directly specify the matrix size (elements are 
uninitialised)

 cout << "A.n_rows: " << A.n_rows << endl;  // .n_rows and .n_cols are read only
 cout << "A.n_cols: " << A.n_cols << endl;

 A(1,2) = 456.0;  // directly access an element (indexing starts at 0)
 A.print("A:");

 A = 5.0;         // scalars are treated as a 1x1 matrix
 A.print("A:");

 A.set_size(4,5); // change the size (data is not preserved)

 A.fill(5.0);     // set all elements to a particular value
 A.print("A:");

 // endr indicates "end of row"
 A << 0.165300 << 0.454037 << 0.995795 << 0.124098 << 0.047084 << endr
   << 0.688782 << 0.036549 << 0.552848 << 0.937664 << 0.866401 << endr
   << 0.348740 << 0.479388 << 0.506228 << 0.145673 << 0.491547 << endr
   << 0.148678 << 0.682258 << 0.571154 << 0.874724 << 0.444632 << endr
   << 0.245726 << 0.595218 << 0.409327 << 0.367827 << 0.385736 << endr;

 A.print("A:");
 det(A);
#if 0
 // determinant
 cout << "det(A): " << det(A) << endl;

 // inverse
 cout << "inv(A): " << endl << inv(A) << endl;

 // save matrix as a text file
 A.save("A.txt", raw_ascii);

 // load from file
 mat B;
 B.load("A.txt");

 // submatrices
 cout << "B( span(0,2), span(3,4) ):" << endl << B( span(0,2), span(3,4) ) << endl;

   //  cout << "B( 0,3, size(3,2) ):" << endl << B( 0,3, size(3,2) ) << endl;

 cout << "B.row(0): " << endl << B.row(0) << endl;

 cout << "B.col(1): " << endl << B.col(1) << endl;

 // transpose
 cout << "B.t(): " << endl << B.t() << endl;

 // maximum from each column (traverse along rows)
 cout << "max(B): " << endl << max(B) << endl;

 // maximum from each row (traverse along columns)
 cout << "max(B,1): " << endl << max(B,1) << endl;

 // maximum value in B
 cout << "max(max(B)) = " << max(max(B)) << endl;

 // sum of each column (traverse along rows)
 cout << "sum(B): " << endl << sum(B) << endl;

 // sum of each row (traverse along columns)
 cout << "sum(B,1) =" << endl << sum(B,1) << endl;

 // sum of all elements
 cout << "accu(B): " << accu(B) << endl;

 // trace = sum along diagonal
 cout << "trace(B): " << trace(B) << endl;

 // generate the identity matrix
 mat C = eye<mat>(4,4);

 // random matrix with values uniformly distributed in the [0,1] interval
 mat D = randu<mat>(4,4);
 D.print("D:");

 // row vectors are treated like a matrix with one row
 rowvec r;
 r << 0.59119 << 0.77321 << 0.60275 << 0.35887 << 0.51683;
 r.print("r:");

 // column vectors are treated like a matrix with one column
 vec q;
 q << 0.14333 << 0.59478 << 0.14481 << 0.58558 << 0.60809;
 q.print("q:");

 // convert matrix to vector; data in matrices is stored column-by-column
 vec v = vectorise(A);
 v.print("v:");

 // dot or inner product
 cout << "as_scalar(r*q): " << as_scalar(r*q) << endl;

 // outer product
 cout << "q*r: " << endl << q*r << endl;

 // multiply-and-accumulate operation (no temporary matrices are created)
 cout << "accu(A % B) = " << accu(A % B) << endl;

 // example of a compound operation
 B += 2.0 * A.t();
 B.print("B:");

 // imat specifies an integer matrix
 imat AA;
 imat BB;

 AA << 1 << 2 << 3 << endr << 4 << 5 << 6 << endr << 7 << 8 << 9;
 BB << 3 << 2 << 1 << endr << 6 << 5 << 4 << endr << 9 << 8 << 7;

 // comparison of matrices (element-wise); output of a relational operator is a umat
 umat ZZ = (AA >= BB);
 ZZ.print("ZZ:");

 // cubes ("3D matrices")
 cube Q( B.n_rows, B.n_cols, 2 );

 Q.slice(0) = B;
 Q.slice(1) = 2.0 * B;

 Q.print("Q:");

 // 2D field of matrices; 3D fields are also supported
 field<mat> F(4,3);

 for(uword col=0; col < F.n_cols; ++col)
 for(uword row=0; row < F.n_rows; ++row)
   {
   F(row,col) = randu<mat>(2,3);  // each element in field<mat> is a matrix
   }

 F.print("F:");
#endif
```

This code is an example that provided by Armadillo website. When I comment

```
det(A)
```

the code can run well. But When I uncomment det(A), the code was crashed and there is no error display in the console. The next code also has the same question. Who can help me for this question? Thanks very much!

Comment: Any more detail from the crash message ?

Comment: From armadillo documentation: If A is not square sized, a std::logic_error exception is thrown. Are you sure A is square sized ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Because this is run well in the Visual Studio 2013. But in the  Qt Creator crashed and the console only show "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Qt\build-paintertest-Desktop_Qt_5_6_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\paintertest.exe crashed."

Comment: How can you be sure if you explicitly set the size to 4 x 5?

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem on my Win64/QtCreator system.
I was writing my own magic wrapper for Armadillo.
Everything went ok until I tryed to calculate determinant.
Application crashed.
After I copied blas_win64_MT.dll and lapack_win64_MT.dll
to the application's folder (in my case it was build/release/)
and now no crashes over there, at least calculation det with.